# Drawable not loading properly

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

i am setting the drawable to a button like this:

```
button.setBackgroundDrawable();
```

I am passing image filename to a method which returns the bitmap and then i am converting that bitmap to drawable like this :

```
Drawable d = BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);
button.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

I have 2 activities A and B , now in A i am setting the button drawable, i go to B and then come back to A at that time the drawable is not visible, but i when i click on the button its visible.

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: You can directly give background in xml file rather than doing dynamically unless it is user selected.

Comment: No its dynamic,so i have go with approach

Comment: In Activity A, where in your code are you setting the background drawable? Could you post the code?

Answer (score 0):

`setBackgroundDrawable()` was deprecated in API 16. Not too long ago, but worth avoiding when `setBackgroundResource(int resId)` and `setBackground(Drawable d)` are available since API 1.

I'd recommend using `setBackgroundResource()` for static stuff and try `setBackground(d)` for the example above.